# GestureRecognizer throws exception in Windows Phone Direct3D App (Native Only)

Tags: visual-c++, directx, windows-phone-8, gesture

I want to use GestureRecognizer in my Windows Phone Game (C++). When I try to create new GestureRecognizer instance the constructor throws exception:

"First-chance exception at 0x76FF277C in TestGesture.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::ClassNotRegisteredException ^ at memory location 0x00B5E674. HRESULT:0x80040154".

I just created a new C++ Windows Phone 8 Direct3D (Native Only) project and added

Windows::UI::Input::GestureRecognizer^  gestureRecognizer = ref new Windows::UI::Input::GestureRecognizer();

in SetWindow(CoreWindow^ window) function.

I followed instructions from this articel http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994931.aspx but it didn't help me.

I spent a few hours trying to figure out the problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've tagged this question with Windows Phone 8, then I assume that's what you're targeting.

In which case, there's a [note near the bottom of this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.aspx) that says:

> **Windows Phone 8**
>   This API is not implemented and will throw an exception if called.

I guess that's what you're seeing.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Do you know how gestures can be recognized in C++ Windows phone 8 (Game)? I write my own gesture recognizer, but it is bad solution.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of anything although Google did find something that may or may not be relevant - http://www.winktoolkit.org/documentation/symbols/wink.ux.GestureRecognizer.html